# Azure AD Enterprise Application - Application Role mapping

Tags: azure-active-directory

The manifest for an App registration in Azure AD looks like the below.

```
"allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
],
    "description": "DocuSign Admin",
    "displayName": "DocuSign Admin",
    "id": "{GUID}",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "lang": null,
    "origin": "Application",
    "value": "42036433"
```

When I map the attribute under provisioning using `SingleAppRoleAssignment([appRoleAssignments]` it returns the name of the role instead of the value. I have to use an expression like `Switch(SingleAppRoleAssignment([appRoleAssignments]), "42036435", "DocuSign Sender", "42036434", "DocuSign Admin", "42036433")` in order for the role to provision correctly.

The Enterprise Application for Zoom expects the name of the role so it works fine, but DocuSign expects the DocuSign Permission Profile ID instead of the name so it doesn't work correctly.

Is there a way to have the mapping return the actual value of the role instead of the name?

Answer (score 2):

as per here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes#provisioning-a-role-to-a-scim-app
I don't have an docusign sub to test, but try this in the target attribute as per the doc.  roles[primary eq "True"].value

you can also try the AppRoleAssignmentsComplex([appRoleAssignments]) as the output seems to include displayname and value.

Hopefully one of these 2 options does what you want.

Comment: That documentation shows multiple options for mapping on the target side. If I was building a custom SCIM endpoint I would have options on passing complex role assignments or other modifications. I have no control over DocuSign SCIM endpoints and the permissionProfileId is expecting a string of the profile id (value not name). I currently modify the source as shown in my question using a switch statement. That works just fine, but seems like a hack rather than the right way to do it. When configuring SSO it does pass the value for the role.

Comment: did you try the complex role assignments? if you look at the sample output of it, it includes the value and display parameters, where as in the simple it only includes value without display. that's why i was wondering if complex included the actual value as the value instead of just the displayname as value.

Comment: I just tried using complex role assignments, but as expected it passed a json object which DocuSign doesn't know how to handle as it is expecting just a simple value string. Looks like this question will go without an answer other than the workaround I currently have in place. I have placed feedback to feedback.azure.com

Comment: Providing link for voting on feedback to Microsoft. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/40671721-singleapproleassignment-approleassignments-shou